# Nodejs simple socket connection doesn't work

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, get, client-server

Every 2 Seconds the client requests data `app.get("/query_data"..`
 I'm connecting to a specific IP Adress + Port.

After connecting, I'm sending a string to this adress to receive data from it. This works well, but only once.

```
var socket = new net.Socket();
app.get("/query_data", function (req, res) {
  socket.connect(2711, '192.168.1.173', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      socket.write("d"); // send "d" to trigger socket.on("data")
    }
  });

  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

Error message I receive:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

However, when I put the `var socket = new net.Socket();` inside `app.get()` it works.

```
app.get("/query_data", function (req, res) {
  var socket = new net.Socket();
  socket.connect(2711, '192.168.1.173', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      socket.write("d");
    }
  });

  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

Why is that? I don't want to create a new socket everytime the client requests data from the server.

Client side, its wrapped in a 2sec `setTimeout()` Function:

```
  $.get("/query_data", function (data) {
      data = data.replace(/[\[\]&]+|nan/g, 'null');
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      (....)
  });
```

Comment: The way you are integrate socket.io with express is bit different. Have a look into the documentation for  initial setup - https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: i'm using net sockets. i suppose they are different to socket.io? on my client side i'm just using a jquery get request.

Comment: yes they are different. Could you please share client side code from where you are calling this endpoint

Comment: i updated the question. might be total bs, I'm a total beginner in node.js

Comment: You are creating new socket connection with `/query_data` api hit that wrong.  Have a look into this link for implementation https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757

Comment: From client side implementation follow this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure, that you end the response process.

using `res.end(data)` instead of `res.send(data)`did the job for me.